# Saving last string from array and show it after open app again

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Here is my code, when my app open again I need to get the last string and string number show on screen. Thanks for help.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
String [] tabela;
TextView textView;
TextView textView2;
TextView textView3;
Button next, prev;
int index;
SharedPreferences sPref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sPref = getSharedPreferences("daniel.myapplication", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sPref.edit();


    // Importing the string array from Valuses folder
    tabela = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array);

    // initialization of textview
    textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView2 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView3 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    //Initialization of buttons
    next =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    prev =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    //OnClickListener for buttons
    next.setOnClickListener(this);
    prev.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Setting values for our variable and textviews
    index = 0;
    textView.setText(tabela[index]);
    textView2.setText(String.valueOf(index+1));
    textView3.setText("/"+String.valueOf(tabela.length));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button2:
            index++;

            if (index==tabela.length){

                index=0;
                textView.setText(tabela[index]);
                textView2.setText(String.valueOf(index+1));
            }else {
                textView.setText(tabela[index]);
                textView2.setText(String.valueOf(index + 1));

            }
            break;

        case R.id.button:
            index--;


            if (index ==-1){

                index = tabela.length -1;
                textView.setText(tabela[index]);
                textView2.setText(String.valueOf(index+1));

        }else {
                textView.setText(tabela[index]);
                textView2.setText(String.valueOf(index + 1));

            }
            break;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Try the problem yourself or do a little more reading before you ask someone else to write your code. Try rephrasing the question using [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to structure

Comment: You have created a sharedPreference but did not used it. I suggest saving the values in onPause and then loading again in onCreate

Comment: Sorry i did not mention i was trying with sharedPreferences and deleted the code which was not working  as i said i am new to programming if someone can show me how to propelry use shared preferences in this case it would be great

Comment: You can use BranMoney answer as a reference and then can check the changes i made in my answer also i should suggest a proper read at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Replace your code with this and it should do the job

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
String [] tabela;
TextView textView;
TextView textView2;
TextView textView3;
Button next, prev;
int index;
SharedPreferences sPref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sPref = getSharedPreferences("daniel.myapplication", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sPref.edit();


    // Importing the string array from Valuses folder
    tabela = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array);

    // initialization of textview
    textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView2 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView3 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    //Initialization of buttons
    next =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    prev =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    //OnClickListener for buttons
    next.setOnClickListener(this);
    prev.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Setting values for our variable and textviews
    index = sPref.getInt("key", 0);
    textView.setText(tabela[index]);
    textView2.setText(String.valueOf(index+1));
    textView3.setText("/"+String.valueOf(tabela.length));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
   super.onPause();
   editor.putInt("key",index);
   editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button2:
            index++;

            if (index==tabela.length){

                index=0;
                textView.setText(tabela[index]);
                textView2.setText(String.valueOf(index+1));
            }else {
                textView.setText(tabela[index]);
                textView2.setText(String.valueOf(index + 1));

            }
            break;

        case R.id.button:
            index--;


            if (index ==-1){

                index = tabela.length -1;
                textView.setText(tabela[index]);
                textView2.setText(String.valueOf(index+1));

        }else {
                textView.setText(tabela[index]);
                textView2.setText(String.valueOf(index + 1));

            }
            break;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks man it works. I really spend a lot of time for looking how to use shared Preferences over the internet and there was only tutorials how to use the to  save and load user name and password. I did not even know i can use this in on pause. I have a lot to learn anyway thanks again and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you have the shared preferences editor set up, what you need to do now is:

- Save whatever you want to shared preferences to load up when you open the screen again
- Load stuff (strings in your case) from shared preferences by overriding onResume() method of the activity or wherever you want to load it

Just as a example for saving:

```
    // Get shared preferences of the application context
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    // Get the editor from the shared preferences
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    // Do what you want here
    editor.putString("string key", "the string you want to save");

    // Commit the changes to the preferences
    editor.commit();
```

Then when you want to load stuff (I suppose the onResume() method)

```
 // Get shared preferences
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    // Get your string from shared preferences
    String yourString = settings.getString("string key", "default string");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer i will try that too to check how it works.

Comment: All good, as Maverick stated - my answer is more of a reference that you can use when necessary in other projects.

Comment: Thanks both of you it will help me to understand sharedPreferences.